# Dynamically fill up rows in a column in pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I want something like this:

```
Id  A  B  Flag  COL
 1  5  4   0     0
 1  5  8   1     1
 1  6  4   0     1
 1  4  7   1     2
 2  7  6   0     0
 2  8  9   1     1
 2  3  8   1     2
```

I have dataframe that has to be partitioned based on id and I have flag based on condition(A<B,Then 1)
and I need to get rows in column based on previous row. Logic is if flag is 1, then COL will be previous row value+1 else if flag is 0, the COL will be value of previous row of column itself.
P.S- We don't have COL column in df, I am creating it based on above logic. My output should be like above mentioned table.

Comment: There is a flaw in your logic. You do not have any ordering rule. If i shuffle your lines, I cannot construct back the dataframe. you need to define a column to order your lines.

Comment: Hi Steven, Logic is whenever I get flag as 1, I need to do +1 to previous row value of "COL" column and whenever I get flag as 0, I just need the same value as previous row value of "COL" column.

Comment: yes, but what if your rows are shuffled ? Spark does shuffle your data, so line with `ID=1` may come one after the other ... on paper, your logic works, but not with dataframe. Please, show your real data, not some example you think is simpler, because it is not.

Comment: Steven, I edited my question . I have used partitioned by and order by 'ID' to get that particular format. Please let me know if it makes any sense now.

Comment: better but still not working. For ID=1, lines do not have any order, so the column COL can change depending on the order of the lines. It can be `0,0,1,2` or `1,2,2,2` or any other combinaison.We need both this new column and the previous one.

Comment: that is the problem, we don't have this 'COL' column, we are creating it based on the condition in 'Flag' column and previous row value of 'COL' column. Code will be  something like this: df = df.withColumn('COL', When(df.Flag == 1), (Lag(df.COL,1)+1).otherwise(Lag(df.COL,1)))

Comment: I understand that. i'm just saying that without any proper ordering column, this output of COL will be different at each run

Comment: yeah, I get it. Do you have any suggestion to remove this ambiguity(output of COL will be different at each run )? like using Row number() or something?

Comment: you need a dataframe with the current ID column (which is a partition column) and the previous ID column you had in your first post (which will be the order column). with these two columns, we will be able to compute the COL.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account the different comments I made, here is my solution based on a valid dataset :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df.show()  # Without columns parition and order, it is impossible to compute COL

+---------+-----+---+---+
|partition|order|  A|  B|
+---------+-----+---+---+
|        1|    1|  5|  4|
|        1|    2|  5|  8|
|        1|    3|  6|  4|
|        1|    4|  4|  7|
|        2|    1|  7|  6|
|        2|    2|  8|  9|
|        2|    3|  3|  8|
+---------+-----+---+---+

df.withColumn("flag", F.when(F.col("A") < F.col("B"), 1).otherwise(0)).withColumn(
    "COL",
    F.sum("flag").over(
        Window.partitionBy("partition").orderBy(
            "order"
        )  # Window is the reason why we need these two columns
    ),
).show()

+---------+-----+---+---+----+---+
|partition|order|  A|  B|flag|COL|
+---------+-----+---+---+----+---+
|        1|    1|  5|  4|   0|  0|
|        1|    2|  5|  8|   1|  1|
|        1|    3|  6|  4|   0|  1|
|        1|    4|  4|  7|   1|  2|
|        2|    1|  7|  6|   0|  0|
|        2|    2|  8|  9|   1|  1|
|        2|    3|  3|  8|   1|  2|
+---------+-----+---+---+----+---+
```